# Application requiring libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 explicitly

Tags: linux, openssl, ld, strace, ldd

I have an application which by doing:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/this/is/another/folder
ldd myApp
// ...
libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10
// ...
```

**First** question: Why myApp links explicitly on libssl.so.10? when in the openssl folder I have (shouldn't link with libssl.so?):

```
/usr/lib64/libssl3.so
/usr/lib64/libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.1e
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.1e
/usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
```

**Second** question: why It gets openssl lib present in /usr/lib64 and not the one in /this/is/another/folder?

Two information: **strace** on my exec gave me (this clearly says that it tried to load libssl.so.10 in my folder but was not there and it shouldn't be as I expect to link with libssl.so):

```
open("/this/is/another/folder/libssl.so.10", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libssl.so.10", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

and the elf of my exec is:

```
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libssl.so.10]
```

**UPDATE**
main makefile sections:

```
SRC = myApp.cpp 
TARGET = myApp
INCLUDE = -I/my/open/ssl/path/include 
LINK = -L/my/open/ssl/path/libs -lssl -lcrypto

CFLAGS = -MMD -MP -c -std=c++0x

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(SRC)
        $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(SRC) $(LINK)
```

Any help is appreciated!

*Kasper*

Comment: We need to see your compile and link commands. The OS would probably be helpful because OS X always links to a dynamic library if its present. You have to work extra hard to link to a static library if a dylib is present.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you link with -lssl, the *link editor* (`ld`) look up `libss.so`, and emits a `DT_NEEDED` tag in the `.dynamic` section of the output file to whatever that file declares itself to be.

That declaration comes from the `DT_SONAME` tag from the `.dynamic` section of `libssl.so` (which is usually a symlink), and it reports `libssl.so.10`.

The *dynamic loader* (`ld.so`) will then read `DT_NEEDED` tag and look for a file named `libsso.so.10`.

I actually [wrote about this](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2009/10/a-shared-library-by-any-other-name/) some years ago, so you can look the for the long-form explanation.